# D3 JS line chart starts from 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am creating a line chart using D3 JS V4. Please refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1qhc2jf/2/).

```
var line = g.append("path")
    .data([lineData])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueLine)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("stroke", "#000");
```

The path is starting from 0 of x axis. According to the data it should start from the first x value. How can I make the path start from the first x value?

Comment: fiddle is not working

Comment: Can you check now? The fiddle is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a band scale, which has an associated bandwidth. Use band scales for bar charts, for instance.

One alternative is using a point scale instead:

```
var x = d3.scalePoint()
.rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.5);
```

Here is the update fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gzf7o6sh/